# Changing column id to associated value in another table

Tags: mysql

I currently have 2 tables

A table that stores all the different values(names) that can be stored in the other.

```
item_slots: 
id | Name

items_list:
id | user_id | i_slot | Name
```

item_slots has 11 entries, whereas items_list can have infinite. During my query of items_list, it can return any amount of items based on the user_id.

I need to replace items_list.i_slot with item_slots.name based on the associated id in i_slot

I am trying the following:

```
SELECT il.* is.name
FROM items_list AS il
JOIN item_slots AS is 
ON is.id = il.i_slot
WHERE il.user_id = 3
```

This returns the following error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.name FROM items_list AS il JOIN item_slots AS is ON is.id = il.i_slot WHERE il' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is` is a keyword in MySQL (as in `IS NULL` et al), try this (escaping the aliases)

```
SELECT il.*, `is`.name
FROM items_list AS il
JOIN item_slots AS `is` 
ON `is`.id = il.i_slot
WHERE il.user_id = 3
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it. (except it needed a comma following `SELECT il.*` in the first line)

Answer (score 2):

`is` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. You must place backticks  around it:

```
SELECT il.*, `is`.name
FROM items_list AS il
JOIN item_slots AS `is` 
ON `is`.id = il.i_slot
WHERE il.user_id = 3
```